# sudo: ulimit: command not found

Tags: sudo, limit

On Ubuntu 12.04, I ran `ulimit -n`, it is showing 1024.  I want to increase my open file limit from 1024 to 65535, so I tried the following command:

```
sudo ulimit -n 65535
```

but I get the following error:

```
sudo: ulimit: command not found
```

How do I increase the file limit from 1024 to 65535?

Comment: Hai thare! Am seeing in my `ulimit` manpage adviced to use the bash builtin `ulimit` instead. Am not sure sudo can be used with builtins, can be it only available for external commands?

Answer (score 43):

Limits are process-specific. `ulimit` is a shell bult-in and can only change limits for this shell and the processes started from this shell. `sudo ulimit` doesn't make any sense. Even if it won't fail it would only influence the processes started by `sudo` at the same time, and there aren't any. It can't change the limit for the current session since it creates a new session (for user root) and terminates it immediately afterwards.

In order to raise your limit above the hard limit you have to either raise the *global* hard limit for *all* users or set a different limit for your *specific* user. Those limits are defined in `/etc/security/limits.conf` (or `/etc/security/limits.d/`). Edit this file and create a new entry for your user:

```
sunpy             hard    nofile           65535
```

Save the file and open a new session. Afterwards calling `ulimit -Hn` inside the new session should show you the new *hard* limit for the number of open files. In order to use the *hard* limit, you have to raise your current *soft* limit to the *hard* limit by calling `ulimit -n 65535`.

Of course you can also change your *soft* limit permanently by specifying *soft* instead of *hard* in your `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Then you don't have to raise your soft limit manually, but the new limit will apply for each of your sessions.

Oh, and [according to this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user) it seems like you have to edit `/etc/pam.d/common-session*` and add:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

if not already done. Otherwise those limits won't apply for your sessions.

Comment: This answer is not helpful.

Comment: Please explain why so that it can be improved.

Comment: @scai I know this is really old but I just hit this problem today so this is still relevant. `ulimit -Hn` aka Hard limits cannot be changed by non-root users once set. (According to RHEL 7.8 man page). So that implies I need to `sudo ulimit -Hn value` but surprise I get the OP's error message. And here I am trying to figure out how to fix it .

Comment: `sudo ulimit ...` will only change the limit for this particular sudo process, so this call is worthless even if it would succeed. You need to either raise the global limit for all users or the global limit for the current user. Both can be done by editing `/etc/security/limits.conf` or creating a new file inside `/etc/security/limits.d/`.